# jQuery UI datepicker translation

Tags: datepicker, translate, jquery-ui-plugins

How can I translate the datepicker from jQuery UI into an other language (german for exaple)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are already [localized versions of the jQuery Datepicker](http://ui.jquery.com/demos/datepicker/#localization). The demo doesn't appear to work as intended, but if you take the source code and build a page, you can see that it works

**EDIT:**

You can see the [working versions here](http://ui.jquery.com/demos/datepicker/localization.html)

Comment: Here is a complete list of the available languajes
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n